# Extension for removing a background/color grradient that is part of "rendering frame" in a browser game

Tags: browser, html5-canvas

I'm making an extension for a game to add the "auto play" function. Basically, when you die the extension presses play automatically.

To do that, I created the script this way: when a menu appears (when you die), press play.

I encountered a first problem, when it autoplays, the menu appears for some ms, which is annoying, so I changed it's display to "none" in certain conditions.

The second problem, when someone dies, in addition to a menu, some blue gradient/image appears that is part of a "rendering frame" according to my friend. It does the same annoying thing, but I can't mmake it dissappear because it's part of a rendering frame.

I want to know if there's a way to remove it, directly, or indirectly using some trick.

here's the [game](https://ryuten.io/play). Press échap so you can see the menu without dying.

If you can't understand what I'm talking about, I just want a trick to remove that blue background that you gonna see when you press échap. Thanks for any help.

here's the script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         你好世界！
// @version      1.1
// @description  RYUTEN!
// @author       Grandy x Ghxst Dz
// @match        https://ryuten.io/play/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    let isMonitoring = false;
    let observer;

    function startMonitoring() {
        if (isMonitoring) {
            document.getElementById('main-canvas').style.opacity = "0";
            return;
        }

        const element = document.getElementById('spectate-info');

        observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
            for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.attributeName === "style") {
                    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element);
                    if (computedStyle.getPropertyValue("display") === "block") {
                        document.getElementById("mame-play-btn").click();
                    }
                }
            }
           const menu = document.getElementById('main-canvas');
           if (menu.style.display === 'block') {
           menu.style.display = 'none';
      }
        });

        observer.observe(element, {
            attributes: true
        });
        isMonitoring = true;
        chatMessageCreator("enabled")
    }

    function stopMonitoring() {
        if (!isMonitoring) {
            return;
        }

        observer.disconnect();
        isMonitoring = false;
        chatMessageCreator("disabled");
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode == 88) {
            if (isMonitoring) {
                stopMonitoring();
            } else {
                startMonitoring();
            }
        }
    });
})();

const chatMessageCreator = (text) => {
    let channel = document.querySelector(".chbx-body-channel");
    let chatMsg = document.createElement("div");
    let date = new Date();
    chatMsg.classList.add("chbx-message");
    channel.appendChild(chatMsg);
    let chatDate = document.createElement("div");
    chatDate.classList.add("chbx-message-time")
    chatDate.innerHTML = `${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`
    chatMsg.appendChild(chatDate);
    let chatSender = document.createElement("div");
    chatSender.classList.add("chbx-message-sender")
    chatSender.innerHTML = "Helper"
    chatMsg.appendChild(chatSender)
    if(text === "enabled") {
        chatSender.style.color = "#00cc00";
    }
    else if(text === "disabled") {
        chatSender.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
    let chatContent = document.createElement("div");
    chatContent.classList.add("chbx-message-content");
    chatContent.innerHTML = `Autorespawn is now ${text}!`
    chatMsg.appendChild(chatContent)
}
```

I looked for the id of that element in the HTML code, looked for the color/background/gradient in the CSS.